# define least common multiple

Tags: abstract-algebra

In Fraleigh, gcd is defined as generator of $H=\{nr+ms\mid n,m \in \Bbb Z\}$

then what about lcm? (exercise 47)
maybe generator of $A\cap B$ where $A$ is cyclic group of $r$, $B$ is cyclic group of $s$

is this right?
then how can I prove 'product of the greatest common divisor and of the least common multiple of r and s is rs'?
(I have seen this problem since childhood and know brief proof, but how in abstract algebra? using $A\cap B$ ??)
further more I am curious exercise 54 of Fraleigh

54. With reference to Exercise 53, what is the situation if $1<m<n$ and $m$ does not divide $n$?
55. Show that in a finite cyclic group $G$ of order $n$, written multiplicatively, the equation $x^m =e$ has exactly $m$ solutions $x$ in $G$ for each positive integer $m$ that divides $n$.

I can easily prove 53, but in 54 which has solution for $\gcd(m,n)$ (I can figure out this, but cannot prove...), how can prove using definition of gcd(or lcd?)

Comment: If by "cyclic group of $r$" you mean the subgroup $\langle r \rangle\subseteq \Bbb Z$ (and not $\Bbb Z$ modulo $r$), then yes, the lcm is the generator of $A\cap B$.

Answer (score 1):

To prove that the product of gcd and lcm of $r,s$ is $rs$, let $m=\text{lcm}(r,s)$ and $d=\text{gcd}(r,s)$, then show $rs|md$ and $md|rs$.

Hint:

To show $rs|md$, let $r=ud, s=vd$, then $rs=(uvd)d$ and use the fact that $m$ divides any common multiplier of $r,s$.

To show $md|rs$, use the fact that $d=ir+js$ for some integers $i,j$.

54. The proof should be similar to 53. Let $m=\text{gcd}(m,n)$ and let $n=sd$. Let $a$ be a generator of $G$. The difference is this time you need to show that

$$\{e, a^s, a^{2s}, ..., a^{(d-1)s}\}$$

is the set of elements that satisfies the equation and the elements are distinct.